# OpenCV - end cap control

Tags: android, opencv

I am attempting to draw a line (with [`line()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line)) with square endings, but can not find any documentation telling me how to do it. So far all my lines end in little triangles.

Can this be done? Is its something to do with lineType?

**EDIT:** An example of my usage...

```
line(ptr_to_mat, Point(10,25), Point(30,25), Scalar(255,0,0,0),4, 8, 0);
```

[image]

**EDIT:** I should have mentioned, this is running on an Android device.

Answer (score 2):

According to [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line), function `line()` will draw **thick lines with rounding endings**.

That said, you cannot directly get over this. But, you can draw it several times with `thickness=1` or draw a filled rectangle instead to achieve your goal (both ugly though :():

```
line(ptr_to_mat, Point(10,23), Point(30,23), CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1, 8, 0);
line(ptr_to_mat, Point(10,24), Point(30,24), CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1, 8, 0);
line(ptr_to_mat, Point(10,25), Point(30,25), CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1, 8, 0);
line(ptr_to_mat, Point(10,26), Point(30,26), CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1, 8, 0);
```

You will get:

[image]

Comment: A filled rectangle (or polygon for lines at an angle) would be better. Even then, its still not a very elegant solution :-(

Comment: @Mick Yes. Probably OpenCV guys think lines with rounding ending are a little bit pretty. :P

Answer (score 0):

Also from the Docs - **"The line is clipped by the image boundaries."** - maybe you can clip the round edges out of the line by drawing the line inside of a Mat's Region Of Interest (ROI, a.k.a. submat). Basically you have to set the dimensions of the ROI with the size of the line minus the round tips. If this sound too complex, it is simpler than that.

It is not very elegant but considering that the clipping is done for free within the line drawing algorithm this probably more efficient than drawing several lines / rectangles.

Another thing, try to change the `lineType` parameter, it might change the tip rendering.

```
lineType:

    8 (or omitted) - 8-connected line.
    4 - 4-connected line.
    CV_AA - antialiased line.
```

Or you can always implement your own line renderer?

I never said it would be pretty :D

Answer (score -1):

the topic is a bit old but I faced this problem recently and I found a solution by using the library wxpython. Maybe it could help, here is a code example:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Draw on Image")

imgBit = wx.Bitmap(width=512, height=512, depth=1)
dc = wx.MemoryDC(imgBit)
pen = wx.Pen(wx.RED, 3)
pen.SetCap(wx.CAP_BUTT)
dc.SetPen(pen)
dc.DrawLines(((32, 32), (64, 32)))
dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
imgBit.SaveFile("bitmap.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

Hope it will help someone in the future